# issue: image carousel skips 1st image

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have an automatic image carousel in javascript for my html website. The carousel has 5 images. The carousel works well on the first round, but on the second round of images, the 1st image doesn't appear. I'm not sure why? Please help if you can

```
<script>
            (function(){    
                    var imgLen = document.getElementById('gallery');
                    var images = imgLen.getElementsByTagName('img');
                    var counter = 1; 

                    if(counter <= images.length){
                        setInterval(function(){    
                            images[0].src = images[counter].src;
                            console.log(images[counter].src);
                            counter++;

                            if(counter === images.length){
                                counter = 1;
                            }
                        },5000);   
                    }
            })();
 </script>
```

Comment: try starting `var counter = 0`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works the first time because your first image, which I'm assuming is the displayed image, starts with the correct source.

It appears that you are overwriting the source of this image with the other sources. After the first round, the original source of the first image is lost.

At the moment, your image sources are probably something like:

```
1,2,3,4,5
2,2,3,4,5
3,2,3,4,5
4,2,3,4,5
5,2,3,4,5
```

for the first round, which is alright. Once the second round starts however, and for subsequent rounds, it would go something like this:

```
2,2,3,4,5
3,2,3,4,5
4,2,3,4,5
5,2,3,4,5
```

The simplest solution would be to store the first image as a 6th image, which would work with your existing code.

An alternative solution would be to store image sources in a JavaScript variable and use those as sources instead of referencing other elements.

Comment: Storing the 1st image as the 6th image worked really well. Thanks so much for the help!

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your first image in the set `images[0]` has its `src` attribute overwritten every time the `setInterval` runs, so its source value has been lost. This means it won't be readable again. Rather than using the 0th item in the set to be the display target for your slideshow, try giving it a unique classname (`<img class="slideshowTarget" src="...">`) and selecting it individually like:

```js
var slideshowTargetImage = document.querySelector('.slideshowTarget');
```

Rather than using `imgLen.getElementsByTagName('img')`, try adding a classname to the images you want to cycle in (`<img class="slideshowImage" src="...">`) and select them with something like:

```js
var images = document.querySelectorAll('.slideshowImage');
```

Next, you'll want the image list to contain the original image again, or it won't be available in your image list. You should put that item at the end, so it'll be in the correct position when it's time for your slideshow to loop.

```html
<div class="slideshow">
  <img class="slideshowTarget" src="0.jpg" />
  <div class="slideshowPreloadImages" style="display: none;">
    <img class="slideshowImage" src="1.jpg" />
    <img class="slideshowImage" src="2.jpg" />
    <img class="slideshowImage" src="3.jpg" />
    <img class="slideshowImage" src="0.jpg" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Next, you can simplify your logic for the loop into one statement that you can run after you set the source on your image. The `%`, or "modulo" operator causes the counter to wrap back around to zero as soon as it grows past `images.length - 1`.

```js
counter = (counter + 1) % images.length;
```

All together!

```js
(function(){
    var slideshowTargetImage = document.querySelector('.slideshowTarget');
    var images = document.querySelectorAll('.slideshowImage');
    var counter = 0;
    var cycleSlideshow = function(){
        var nextImageSource = images[counter].src;
        slideshowTargetImage.src = nextImageSource;
        console.log('nextImageSource', nextImageSource);
        counter = (counter + 1) % images.length;
    };
    if (images.length) { // we can now test whether it's 0/falsy, becacuse the target is not part of the set!
        setInterval(
          cycleSlideshow,
          1000
        );   
    }
})();
```